# Show Data from Multiple Tables with connected id in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I have two tables in my SQLite database, first **users** and second **jobs**, where a user can have multiple jobs to do

Data in `users` table

```
id      name
1        Me
2       You
```

where `id` generated through : **id integer primary key autoincrement**

Data in `jobs` table

```
id     jobname     userid
1       JobA          2
2       JobB          2
3       JobC          1
```

where `id` generated through : **id integer primary key autoincrement**

where `user_id` fetched from **users** table

Now, I would like to `loop` through all the users and jobs table one by one, if user has some job to do then need to show **Toast**

```
JobC assigned to user1
```

**DatabaseHandler.java:**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

..................

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + 
              "(id integer primary key autoincrement," +
              " name text);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_JOBS + 
              "(id integer primary key autoincrement," +
              " jobname text" +
              " userid long);");        
}

// Insert data into users table
public long InsertUsers(String name) {

     try {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

        ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
        Val.put("name", name); 

        long rows = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, Val);

        db.close();
        return rows; // return rows inserted.

     } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
     }
}

    // Insert data into jobs table
public long InsertJobs(String jobname, long userid) {

     try {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

        ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
        Val.put("jobname", jobname); 
        Val.put("userid", userid); 

        long rows = db.insert(TABLE_JOBS, null, Val);

        db.close();
        return rows; // return rows inserted.

     } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
     }
}   

public String[] getUsersId() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
             String[] data = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            int id_row=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                Log.d("TAG","id is ::"+id_row);             

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_JOBS);
    onCreate(db);
 }

}
```

And in MainActivity.java:

```
    DatabaseHandler dh;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            dh = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

            buttonGetData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dh.getUsersId();
                }
            });

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using join:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT j.jobname, u.name FROM jobs j JOIN users u ON j.userid=u.id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the exact code but try to execute the query something similar to this. And do a little research before asking the question.

```
String newQuery="SELECT db1.your_column db2.you_coloum2 from table1 db1, table2 db2 where db2.u_id=db1.id;
```

fetch the results using Cursor